# How to insert a record in a child table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have 3 tables with names `user` and `video` and `recommendedvideos`.
The `user` tables saves the information about registered users and the `recommendedvideos` table saves information about which video a user selected as his favourite video.

```
video table  
-------------
Variable(pk),
Title,
User(fk for userTbl)
```

```
user table
-----------
User(pk),
Pass
```

```
recommendedvideos table
------------------------------
Variable(pk, fk for videoTBL),
User(pk, fk for userTBL),
date,
status
```

My problem is when i want to insert a record in recommendedvideos table i face with a problem although I observe the constraints for fk.

```
com.CommandText = " Insert into recommendedvideos(Variable, User, Date, Status )"
                    + "VALUES(Variable, User, Date, Status )";

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Variable", Variable);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", User);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status);

            connect.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();
```

I receive this error

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`aspdb`.`recommendedvideos`, CONSTRAINT `recommendedvideos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Variable`) REFERENCES `video` (`Variable`))

What's wrong about my code?

Comment: how have you made the Primary keys for recommendation table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Just noticed that you *didn't set* your *parameters correctly* within your statement! Any parameter must have a @ in front (assumed that you are using an ***[SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) and SqlCommand*** object. If you are using ***OleDbCommand*** use [this syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) instead

```
com.CommandText = " Insert into recommendedvideos(Variable, User, Date, Status )"
                + "VALUES(@Variable, @User, @Date, @Status )";

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Variable", Variable);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", User);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status);

        connect.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connect.Close();
```

Comment: Dear Pilgerstorfer
Im sure that there is a value for variable field in table videos that i want to insert the same value of it inside recommendedvideos table and also for User field in user table. i aslo use debug tools in vs2010 but it seems every things are working very well. Do u have any idea ? TQ

Comment: rewrote answer as of given details - hope that helps!

Comment: OMG! What a unwise mistake i did! It works now. Tq so much all of my friends :)

Comment: if you found my answer useful - you may consider marking it as best answer - thx in advance

Comment: Sorry dear  Pilgerstorfer Franz. Im not familiar there.